# How to handle return statement in Java code with checkstyle?

Tags: java, syntax, checkstyle

I have 2 methods.  I am using checkstyle on my code. I have extracted the `buildResultWithLabel()` from `buildResult()`.

Problematic Code:

```
    final int issueNo = commitMessage.getIssueNumber();
    if (processedIssueNumbers.contains(issueNo)) {
        return;
    }
    processedIssueNumbers.add(issueNo);
```

Before extracting the method, the code was in `buildResult()`. Now that I have extracted it, it is no longer running in a loop. Before it was a `continue;` instead of a `return;`.

> ERROR: (coding) ReturnCount: Return count is 1 (max allowed for void
> methods/constructors/lambdas is 0).

My code looks like this:

```
public static Result buildResult(String localRepoPath, String authToken, String remoteRepoPath,
                                 String startRef, String endRef) throws IOException,
                                  GitAPIException {

    final Result result = new Result();

    final GHRepository remoteRepo = createRemoteRepo(authToken, remoteRepoPath);
    final Set<RevCommit> commitsForRelease =
        getCommitsBetweenReferences(localRepoPath, startRef, endRef);
    commitsForRelease.removeAll(getIgnoredCommits(commitsForRelease));

    final Set<Integer> processedIssueNumbers = new HashSet<>();
    for (RevCommit commit : commitsForRelease) {
        CommitMessage commitMessage = new CommitMessage(commit.getFullMessage());
        if (commitMessage.isRevert()) {
            System.out.println(commitMessage.getMessage());
            commitMessage = new CommitMessage(commitMessage.getRevertedCommitMessage());
        }
        buildResultWithLabel(remoteRepoPath, result, remoteRepo, commitsForRelease,
                             processedIssueNumbers,
                             commit,
                             commitMessage);
    }
    return result;
}

private static void buildResultWithLabel(String remoteRepoPath, Result result,
                                         GHRepository remoteRepo,
                                         Set<RevCommit> commitsForRelease,
                                         Set<Integer> processedIssueNumbers, RevCommit commit,
                                         CommitMessage commitMessage) throws IOException {
    if (commitMessage.isIssueOrPull()) {
        final int issueNo = commitMessage.getIssueNumber();
        if (processedIssueNumbers.contains(issueNo)) {
            return;
        }
        processedIssueNumbers.add(issueNo);

        final GHIssue issue = remoteRepo.getIssue(issueNo);
        if (issue.getState() != GHIssueState.CLOSED) {
            result.addWarning(String.format(MESSAGE_NOT_CLOSED, issueNo, issue.getTitle(),
                                            remoteRepoPath, issueNo));
        }

        final String issueLabel = getIssueLabelFrom(issue);
        if (issueLabel.isEmpty()) {
            final String error = String.format(MESSAGE_NO_LABEL,
                                               issueNo,
                                               Arrays.stream(Constants.ISSUE_LABELS)
                                                   .collect(Collectors.joining(SEPARATOR)),
                                               remoteRepoPath, issueNo);
            result.addError(error);
        }
        final List<GHLabel> releaseLabels = getAllIssueLabels(issue);
        if (releaseLabels.size() > 1) {
            final String error = String.format(MESSAGE_MORE_THAN_ONE_RELEASE_LABEL,
                                               issueNo,
                                               Arrays.stream(Constants.ISSUE_LABELS)
                                                   .collect(Collectors.joining(SEPARATOR)),
                                               remoteRepoPath, issueNo);
            result.addError(error);
        }
        final Set<RevCommit> issueCommits = getCommitsForIssue(commitsForRelease, issueNo);
        final String authors = getAuthorsOf(issueCommits);
        final ReleaseNotesMessage releaseNotesMessage =
            new ReleaseNotesMessage(issue, authors);
        result.putReleaseNotesMessage(issueLabel, releaseNotesMessage);
    }
    else {
        // Commits that have messages which do not contain issue or pull number
        final String commitShortMessage = commit.getShortMessage();
        final String author = commit.getAuthorIdent().getName();
        final ReleaseNotesMessage releaseNotesMessage =
            new ReleaseNotesMessage(commitShortMessage, author);
        result.putReleaseNotesMessage(Constants.MISCELLANEOUS_LABEL, releaseNotesMessage);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

"Single return path permitted" is an opinion about code readability, and you've discovered that strictly applying it can make your code much less readable by preventing early-exit when you calculate that you don't need to do a bunch of work.

The best option is to change your Checkstyle policy and turn off this rule. If you absolutely can't (a non-programmer manager has decided on "best policies"), then you can extract the remainder of your method into another private method and `if (!contains) { longProcess(); }`.

Comment: Agreed.  If tools give bad advice, don't follow that advice - turn off the tool.